# Handling value of DateTimePicker in React Native with Formik

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik

I am using Formik to create a reminder form that store some information, including date and time. And I've encountered a problem while using `DateTimePicker` from `react-native-modal-datetime-picker` in my form.

My main goal is when a user press a Date or Time input, `DateTimePicker` will be shown. After user choose the time,  `DateTimePicker` will pass that value to the input and display that input onto screen. And when user press 'Submit' button, log console will print out the `values` props of `Formik`

Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import {Button, Input} from 'react-native-elements'
import ModalDropdown from 'react-native-modal-dropdown'
import DateTimePicker from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker'
import {Formik} from 'formik'
import * as yup from 'yup'

export default class ReminderForm extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           isDatePickerVisible: false,
           isTimePickerVisible: false,
           reminder: {
               date: '',
               time: '',
               //...more properties go here
           }
        }
    }
    showDatePicker = () => {//show the picker for Date input
        this.setState({ isDatePickerVisible: true });
    };

    hideDatePicker = () => {
        this.setState({ isDatePickerVisible: false });
    };
    handleDatePicked = date => {
        let newDate = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString();
        this.setState(prevState=> ({
            ...prevState,
            isDatePickerVisible: !prevState.isDatePickerVisible,
            reminder: {
                ...prevState.reminder,
                date: newDate
            }
        }));
        console.log(this.state);
    };
    showTimePicker = () => {//show the picker for time input
        this.setState({ isTimePickerVisible: true });
    };

    hideTimePicker = () => {
        this.setState({ isTimePickerVisible: false });
    };
    handleTimePicked = time => {
        let newTime = new Date(time).toLocaleTimeString();
        this.setState(prevState=> ({
            ...prevState,
            isTimePickerVisible: !prevState.isTimePickerVisible,
            reminder: {
                ...prevState.reminder,
                time: newTime
            }
        }))
        console.log(this.state)
    };
    render(){
        return(
            <View style = {{flex:1}}>
                 <Formik initialValues = {this.state.reminder}
                        onSubmit={()=> console.log('Submitted')}
                       >
                     {
                         ({values,handleChange,errors,setFieldTouched,touched,isValid,handleSubmit})=>(
                            <View style ={{flex:1, justifyContent:'space-around'}}>
                                <TouchableOpacity style ={{flex:1, marginTop: 10, marginBottom:10, backgroundColor:null}}
                                                  onPress={this.showDatePicker}>
                                    <Input value = {values.date}  inputContainerStyle={{height: '60%'}} onChangeText={handleChange('date')}
                                           onBlur={()=>setFieldTouched('date')} label = "Date" labelStyle = {{fontSize: 15}}/>
                                </TouchableOpacity>  
                                <DateTimePicker mode="date" isVisible={this.state.isDatePickerVisible} 
                                                 onConfirm={this.handleDatePicked} onCancel={this.hideDatePicker}/>
                                <TouchableOpacity style ={{flex:1, marginTop: 10, marginBottom:10, backgroundColor:null}}
                                                  onPress={this.showTimePicker}>
                                    <Input value = {values.time}  
                                           onChangeText={handleChange('time')} inputContainerStyle={{height: '60%'}}
                                           onBlur={()=>setFieldTouched('time')} label = "Time" labelStyle = {{fontSize: 15}}/>
                                </TouchableOpacity>          
                                <DateTimePicker mode="time" isVisible={this.state.isTimePickerVisible} 
                                                 onConfirm={this.handleTimePicked} onCancel={this.hideTimePicker}/>

                             //..more inputs go here
                                 <Button containerStyle = {{flex:1, marginTop: 10, marginBottom:0}} TouchableComponent={TouchableOpacity}
                                        onPress={()=> console.log(values)}  title = "Submit" titleStyle = {{fontSize: 15}}/> 


                            </View> 
                         )
                     }
                 </Formik>
            </View>
         )
    }

}
```

When I ran this code, date and time input did not show the value I chose in `DateTimePikcker` before, and when I submit form `date` and `time` property in `values` props got null. Then I tried to fix the input's attribute:

```js
 <TouchableOpacity style ={{flex:1, marginTop: 10, marginBottom:10, backgroundColor:null}}
                                                  onPress={this.showDatePicker}>
                                    <Input value = {this.state.reminder.date}  inputContainerStyle={{height: '60%'}} onChangeText={handleChange('date')}
                                           onBlur={()=>setFieldTouched('date')} label = "Date" labelStyle = {{fontSize: 15}}/>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
```

In this time the input did show value I chose from `DateTimePicker` but when I submit form the `date` property still return to null. The problem is that I don't know how to change the property in the `values` props of `Formik` when user chooses date in `DateTimePicker`. Can you guy help me to figure it out?

And one more problem is that `handleSubmit` props does not work in here. I try to put the `console.log()` in `onSubmit` attribute (you can see in my code above) but it's not working.

Comment: `setState` is [async](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), `console.log` immediately after is meaningless - it can be logged from `render` or viewed from React DevTools (and it's similar for [hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877875/1176601))

Answer (score 11):

Below is an example.  Notice the use of Formik's [setFieldValue](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void).

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import DateTimePickerModal from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';
import moment from 'moment';

export default function Example() {
  return (
    <Formik initialValues={{ myDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') }} onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}>
      {({ handleSubmit, values, setFieldValue }) => (
        <MyForm values={values} setFieldValue={setFieldValue} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}

export const MyForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, values, setFieldValue } = props;
  const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisibility] = useState(false);

  const showDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(true);
  };

  const hideDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(false);
  };

  const handleConfirm = date => {
    setFieldValue('myDate', moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
    hideDatePicker();
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text onPress={showDatePicker}>{moment(values.myDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}</Text>
      <DateTimePickerModal
        isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
        mode="date"
        onConfirm={handleConfirm}
        onCancel={hideDatePicker}
        date={moment(values.myDate).toDate()}
      />
      <Button title="Submit" onPress={handleSubmit} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Know why I am getting this error - `a date or time should be specified as value`

Answer (score 0):

I made an `example` for you. Please refer to this and fill out the code.

[Example Link](https://snack.expo.io/@taeeh/modal-datetilepicker-examples)

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, View,TextInput } from "react-native";
import DateTimePicker from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";

let date_pick;
export default class DateTimePickerTester extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isDateTimePickerVisible: false,
      reminder:{
        date: "8/24/2009"
      }
    };
  }

  showDateTimePicker = () => {
    date_pick = new Date(this.state.reminder.date);
    this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: true });
  };

  hideDateTimePicker = () => {
    this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: false });
  };

  handleDatePicked = date => {
    console.log("A date has been picked: ", date);
    this.hideDateTimePicker();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"}}>
        <Button title="Show DatePicker" onPress={this.showDateTimePicker} />
        <DateTimePicker
          isVisible={this.state.isDateTimePickerVisible}
          onConfirm={this.handleDatePicked}
          onCancel={this.hideDateTimePicker}
          date={date_pick}
        />
         <TextInput value = {this.state.reminder.date} style={{width:"80%",height:20,borderColor:"red",borderWidth:1}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the usage of Formik here?

Comment: @AbhiBurk  Same usage as Textinput.

Comment: I don't think so it has  to be slighly different then the shown above

Comment: @AbhiBurk My example is the code form of the question.But You can't use it as it is. Of course you have to apply it.

Comment: `<TextInput value = {this.state.reminder.date}` instead of this how one can set value in formik field ?